# Layout with two TextViews and ellipsis

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-constraintlayout, ellipsis

I want to create a layout with two TextViews in one row. I want the first TextView to be ellipsized if its text is too long. I want them to behave as if they had the width of `wrap_content` if they can both fit in the row. How do I do it?

Here's the result I want to get:

[Short text1][text2]

[Very long text1 that has to be ellipsized...][text2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a horizontal chain of the two views, set max lines to one of the left view and set the constrained width of the left view to `true` to keep it in bounds:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:maxLines="1"
        app:layout_constrainedWidth="true"
        android:text="Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! Hello World! "
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="packed"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add these two lines in your xml layout to your TextView that may need ellipses.

android:ellipsize="end"
android:maxLines="1"